# What is the correct way to pass parameters to function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In my javascript code i have the following:

```
function foo(param1) {
    setInterval( bar(param1), 3000 );
}

function bar(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

function set() {
    foo('hello');
}
```

And on page load i call `set()`, it gives the alert message only once. Why it does not work as i would expect.? I think the problem is with the parameter that i am passing the `foo()` function, but what it is exactly, i am not able to figure out.

If the problem is with the parameter, what can be an alternate way to achieve the desired result.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `setInterval`, you are executing a function and passing it's return value (`undefined` since the function executed does not have a return value).

Try using an anonymous function instead:

```
function foo(param1) {
    setInterval(function () {
        bar(param1);
    }, 3000);
}

function bar(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

`param1` never changes here, so there is no need for anything more complicated. [Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/spvkV/)

Comment: Thanks. So its Anonymous function, not a closure.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to access the parameter from a function that you pass to `setInterval`:

```
function foo(param1) {
    setInterval(function () {
        bar(param1);
    }, 3000);
}

function bar(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

function set() {
    foo('hello');
}
```

Comment: For my daily dose of pedantry, there are no closures in this code. From the question you linked to: "That is not a closure. A closure is when you return the inner function. The inner function will close-over the variables of foo before leaving."

Comment: @jbabey Fair enough, I stand corrected. :) So I can correct the answer, what's the proper term for a function accessing variables from its parent context?

Comment: @PhilBooth it's just an anonymous function declaration declared inside a named (`foo`) function declaration.

Comment: @jbabey Actually, having read the comments to that answer, the other answers to that question and the article about closures on wikipedia, I disagree. :) It's not necessary to *return* the function for it to be a closure, only that the function runs and has access to the enclosing context after the parent function has already returned. Which it does, in this case.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding this. For the function `bar(param1)` that will be called at an interval of 3 secs; in which context/scope will it be called.? Will `setInterval(function() { bar(param1); }, 3000 );` translate to `setInterval(function() { bar('hello'); }, 3000 );` when the function `foo(param1)` is called as `foo('hello');` .? I am asking this because at the next interval when `bar(param1)` gets called, it will not be inside `foo(param1)`, so at this time, what will be the value of `param1` that will be passed as `msg`to `bar(msg)` .? Its confusing.

Comment: @pratik That scenario is fine. The way to think about it is that you are defining a brand new function every time you invoke `foo` and those functions all have perpetual, dynamic access to their context. A second invocation of `foo` in your case will create a second closure, which accesses a second context. The scenario to be careful of is when you want to define a closure inside the body of a loop. In that case you must call a function outside the body of the loop, fixing the context of each loop iteration, otherwise every closure will refer to a single context (the terminal loop iteration).

Comment: @Phil Ok, I got some some idea about this from your explanation. So the function `bar(msg)` will be called in the `foo(param1)` context at each interval because the function `bar(msg)` was defined in `foo(param1)`. About the 2nd scenario you mentioned about the terminal loop iteration, its really tricky and i have experienced it personally :D. Learning from mistakes :).. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` expects a function while you're giving the return value of calling the whole function.

A modified version that should work:

```
var msg = null;

function foo(param1) {
   // When foo is called, its argument is set to msg variable, so the function called 
   // by setInterval will have access to the message that must show in a window.alert
    msg = param1;
    setInterval(bar, 3000 );
}

function bar() {
    alert(msg);
}

function set() {
    foo('hello');
}
```

Comment: While this will work with the global variable, i want `bar(msg)` to alert exactly the parameter `msg`'s value that i have passed to it.

Comment: @patrik You're not right. This approach does what you want. Other discussion is that the closure approach is better, but I just wanted to show you were your code was wrong and a basic hint on how to get it working.

Comment: Yes, your answer is right and it does the job, but what if i do not want to create a global variable.? So in that case i will have to use the anonymous function approach.

Comment: @pratik In my devs, I would never use global vars. I thought you could

Comment: Nope, even i do not want to use global vars. I should have been more specific about that in the question.

Comment: @pratik The comment was sent in a wrong way. I mean that the problem in your question was your misunderstanding of what `setInterval` expects. Actually I don't like to provide the exact solution, I thought you could go beyond an SO answer ;)

Comment: Yes, correct, the problem was i misunderstood the parameter that `setInterval()` expected, and the answers cleared that. Thanks. :)